# Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

connecting firebase real-time database with assistant
when adding the dependencies of firebase database this error is showing:

```
Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0
```

this also happened with authentication

My android studio version 3.2 build September 18

[image]

Comment: If you give a *negative* score to a question, it's helpful to explain **why**!  Otherwise, new folks like @Sadi are chased away from using this excellent resource.

Comment: +1 Don't dislike the question as it is a really necessary question that many may come across. At least give the reason of why when you do.

Answer (score 14):

There's an annoying bug in the new versions of Android Studio (I've seen versions 3.2.1 or higher on both Windows and Mac).
if you integrate firebase automatically from tools, Thןד gives you an unwanted add-on that de-compile the program.

for example:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

instead of:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

Just drop the unnecessary extra after the ':'

Note that the example is for a database
If you need something else substitute the word database in your library, for example ads.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Remove,

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

Add following lines and sync project.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
```

**Note**: use the latest version from https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. but now worked for me.Try This add the dependency for Authentication to your app-level build.gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

When you click on add dependency this again ask you add the statement `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'` So This button does not need to be triggered to authenticate the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can update this in the app/Build Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This must help you to get rid of the error!

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me ! You can try !

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Update your gradle ***in the root*** `Build.gradle` first:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

Then use & update this in the `app/Build.gradle` dependencies:

```
implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2
```

---

I believe you're trying to download another non-exist dependency, that's why you get the error:

```
Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0
```

Check: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-database/16.0.2

And here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: You are actually setting two versions for the firebase database: `firebase-database-16.0.1:15.0.0` *this is not correct**, use my answer for that. However, there is another issue with the appcompat.

Answer (score 0):

I get a issue like this sometimes, 1)restart the PC, or 2) delete C:\Users\.gradle and then restart the machine.

If you are using ionic then delete the .ionic as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

```
Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0
```

Because you are using a wrong dependency in your code. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
```

Because such a version `16.0.1:15.0.0` does not exist.

Please also add the following dependency which is now mandatory:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
```

> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.

In your top level `build.gradle` file please be sure to have the latest version of Google Service plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท I cannot consider it as a duplicate since your answer in my opinion is incomplete. The OP cannot use `firebase-database` dependency without using the implementation of `firebase-core`. I'm trying to help the OP because I saw his comment from your answer: `Not Helping I have tried everything you said.`.

Comment: Hi Sadi! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

When adding Firebase dependencies, always try finding the latest version it.
As of this time: firebase-database:16.0.5
But always check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 0):

Just delete 15:0.0 and rebuild the project. It works
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5:15.0.0'