# ERROR: Failed to resolve: firebase-database

Tags: android, firebase

[image]
I am trying to use firebase with my App and i did all the steps listed in the official website of firebase on how to add the google-service plugin and the firebase products into both my module and project build.gradle , but i still got this list of errors :

1-ERROR: Failed to resolve: firebase-database

2-ERROR: Failed to resolve: firebase-common

3-ERROR: Failed to resolve: firebase-database-collection

4-ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-annotations

here's my project:buidl.gradle:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        google()
    }
}
```

here's my app build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'

    // Displaying images

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image]

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
 #Mon Jan 06 14:06:26 EET 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: did these errors came from `sync`?

Comment: Have you download **google-services.json** and paste into **`app`** folder in your project?

Comment: @Ticherhaz yes they did

Comment: @Ali yes and i added google-services plugin

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52585654/failed-to-resolve-firebase-database-15-0-0

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: @linasaeed, can you add your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman check out the post , i added it

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
 // Add the SDKs for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
 // For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'

 // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure that you've added
 // Google's Maven repository to your root-level build.Gradle file
}
```

You can add any of the [supported Firebase products](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0#available-libraries)  to your Android app. [For more detail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0)